# Material UI Modal not working in React, using example

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to copy the example of a modal from material UI but when I click on the button that displays the modal, nothing happens except a grey transparent overlay.

The state is being set when I console.log(open) so I'm not sure why nothing is happening

I used this example https://mui.com/material-ui/react-modal/

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import Modal from 'material-ui/Modal';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';

const TaskDrawer = ({
  action
}) => {

const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

function rand() {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * 20) - 10;
}

function getModalStyle() {
  const top = 50 + rand();
  const left = 50 + rand();

  return {
    top: `${top}%`,
    left: `${left}%`,
    transform: `translate(-${top}%, -${left}%)`,
  };
}

    const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
    const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);

    return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        Tasks
      </h1>
      <div>
        {action == "Find" &&
            (
            <Button
                className="edit"
                onClick={handleOpen}
            >
                Edit
            </Button>     
        )}
      </div>
        <Modal
            open={open}
            onClose={handleClose}
        >
            <div style={getModalStyle()} className="modal">
                <h2 id="simple-modal-titile">Text in a modal </h2>
                <p id="simple-modal-description">test of a modal </p>
            </div>
        </Modal>   
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        {Object.keys(tasks).map(k => getTask(k, tasks[k]))}
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};
export default taskDrawer;
```

Comment: can you post your current example in https://codepen.io/?

Comment: As MUI said Modal is a lower-level construct that is leveraged by Dialog. So if you use Dialog it would be better, The performace is same.